# How import swagger into postman with environment?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, swagger, postman

I created asp.net core API with swagger.
And when I import it is not usable because request looks like "http:///api/Account/login" and API it is not an environment variable.

So, how setup swagger for use environment. It should look like "http:///**{{api}}**/Account/login"

Answer (score 2):

in your startup class you must add correctly middleWare of swagger:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            ...
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "app title", Version = "v1"});
            });
            services.AddSwaggerDocumentation();
            ...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
        ...
        app.UseSwagger((c) =>
        {
            c.RouteTemplate = "docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        });
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/docs/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
        ...
}
```